# How should I transpose date column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

[image]

I wish to transpose it to:

[image]

I understand that this might be a basic question, therefore, if someone could direct me to the correct references so I can try to figure out how to do so in `pandas`.

Comment: Could you paste tables instead of images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try  with `melt()` and `set_index()`:

```
out=(df.melt(id_vars=['Market','Product'],var_name='Date',value_name='Value')
       .set_index('Date'))
```

If needed use:

```
out.index.name=None
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: @ilovewt did you get your expected output?

Comment: works like a charm, thanks again, yesterday I saw your answer but they said I cannot upvote within 5 minutes, so I forgot!